# Parâmetro chegando de maneira truncada em requisição Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net, get

Tenho uma requisição `Ajax` que obtém os dados que preciso a partir de um `WebMethod`. O problema é que o parâmetro utilizado para a requisição está "chegando" truncado no `WebMethod` o comprimento do parâmetro é de 44 dígitos.

Parâmetro enviado: `31161102996615000145550000000413281487877818`.

Como está chegando: `3.1161102996615E+43`

Código Ajax:

```
var valorCampo= $(this).attr('data-clipboard-text');
var content = "parametroConsulta=" + encodeURIComponent(valorCampo);

$.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "myPage.aspx/ObtenhaDados",
        data: content,
        success: function (data) { dadosObtidos(data); },
        error: function (data) { falhaConsulta(data); }

});
```

`WebMethod`:

```
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
 public static DadosPessoais ObtenhaDados(string valoPesquisa)
 { .... }
```

Url exibida no FireBug:

`http://localhost:61187/ps/myPage.aspx/ObtenhaDados?valoPesquisa=31161102996615000145550000000413281487877818`

Comment: `content` na requisição Ajax é uma string? Tente usar número para `content` e `float` para assinatura do método `ObtenhaDados`

Comment: Sim `content` é uma `string`...

Comment: Tente mudar o método de envio no jQuery para "POST", ficando assim: `var content = "{ parametroConsulta: " + encedURIComponent(valorCampo) + " }"`

Comment: Número grande demais, ele está sendo convertido para uma base legível. Se você der um `alert(31161102996615000145550000000413281487877818);` a saída será `3.1161102996615E+43`. Ele está sendo convertido para notação cientifica.

Comment: Isso mesmo, é isso que estou tentando resolver, por isso ele esta como `string` rsrsrsrsr

Comment: Com essa quantidade de número não creio que funcione. O que você poderia usar com uma quantidade menor de número seria `Number` e `toPrecision` ou `toFixed`. 44 dígitos é muita coisa, até para um computador.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema colocando o parâmetro entre "'". Código abaixo:

```
var valorCampo = $(this).attr('data-clipboard-text');
var content = {valorPesquisa: "'" + valorCampo + "'"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma irá passar o valor como uma string e concatenar com o parametroConsulta, mas você poderia fazer isso no c#

```
var valorCampo= $(this).attr('data-clipboard-text');
var content = "parametroConsulta=" + valorCampo.toString();

$.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "myPage.aspx/ObtenhaDados",
        data: content,
        success: function (data) { dadosObtidos(data); },
        error: function (data) { falhaConsulta(data); }

});
```

Comment: Só uma coisa, no caso ele já vem como string quando você pega o attr. Só verificar usando typeOf.

Comment: o `toString()` não funfou... :(

Comment: @JcSaint você está enviando como String e recebendo como string ?

Comment: Envio como `string` e recebo um `Json`